# I am using MinGw compiler, whenever I'm trying to debug the code gets error failed. And why its location is of cygwin as I am using mingw

Tags: c, debugging, compiler-errors, cygwin, mingw

```
Active debugger config: GDB/CDB debugger:Default
Building to ensure sources are up-to-date
Selecting target: 
Debug
Adding source dir: H:\C Language\Character-Strings-(Demonstration)-Utilizing-common-string-functions-Source-code\
Adding source dir: H:\C Language\Character-Strings-(Demonstration)-Utilizing-common-string-functions-Source-code\
Adding file: H:\C Language\Character-Strings-(Demonstration)-Utilizing-common-string-functions-Source-code\bin\Debug\CommonStringFunctionsExample.exe
Changing directory to: "H:/C Language/Character-Strings-(Demonstration)-Utilizing-common-string-functions-Source-code/."
Set variable: PATH=.;C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\mingw64;C:\Cygwin\bin;C:\Cygwin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;F:\runtime\win64;F:\tools\pcb\bin;F:\tools\fet\bin;F:\tools\specctra\bin;F:\tools\bin;F:\tools\PSpice\Library;F:\tools\Capture;C:\Program Files (x86)\IVI Foundation\VISA\WinNT\Bin;C:\Program Files\IVI Foundation\VISA\Win64\Bin;F:\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\saihi\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\saihi\Anaconda3\Library\ssl;C:\ProgramData\saihi\atom\bin;C:\Users\saihi\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
Starting debugger: C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\mingw64\bin\gdb.exe -nx -fullname -quiet  -args "H:/C Language/Character-Strings-(Demonstration)-Utilizing-common-string-functions-Source-code/bin/Debug/CommonStringFunctionsExample.exe"
done
Setting breakpoints
Debugger name and version: GNU gdb (GDB) 8.1
Starting the debuggee failed: No executable specified, use `target exec'.
Debugger finished with status 0
```

Comment: Please provide some more context. What commands are you using? Did you look up and check the options given to GDB? Why do you think Cygwin is its (GDB's?) location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need GDB to debug code built with MinGW's gcc.

Here's a link explaining how it can be done: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cpp-debug

Also it looks like you're using an old version (GDB 8.1 while the current version is 9.2). Check out http://winlibs.com/ for a build of the latest version of MinGW-w64 which includes GDB 9.2.